# How to prove $\|(u-\eta \nabla f(u))-(v-\eta \nabla f(v))\| \leq\|u-v\|$?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, gradient-descent

How to prove the following theory?

If $f: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is convex and $\beta$-smooth and $0<\eta \leq 2 / \beta$, then for every $u, v \in \mathbb{R}^d$,
$$
\|(u-\eta \nabla f(u))-(v-\eta \nabla f(v))\| \leq\|u-v\| .
$$

It seems to be a very famous conclusion, where can I find some reference of it?

Comment: Sometimes finding a proof for a simple result is a pain. Do you need the reference? The proof is 1/2 lines.

Comment: @AsAnExerciseProve . Yes and thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the square of the left hand side and expand the norm. You get
$$
\| u - v \|^2 + \underbrace{\eta^2 \| \nabla f(u) - \nabla f(v)\|^2 -
2\eta \langle u - v, \nabla f(u) - \nabla f(v) \rangle}_{(\sharp)}.
$$

We now use the following (for a proof, see Thm. 2.1.5 in Nesterov's [*Lectures on Convex Optimization*](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-91578-4)):

> **Fact**: The gradient of a convex and $\beta$-smooth function $f$ is co-coercive, meaning that
> $$ \langle \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y), x - y \rangle \geq \frac{1}{\beta} \|\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)\|^2, \; \; \forall x, y. $$

Using this, we obtain

$$
(\sharp) = \eta^2 \| \nabla f(u) - \nabla f(v) \|^2 - 2 \eta \langle u - v, \nabla f(u) - \nabla f(v) \rangle \leq
\left( \eta^2 - \frac{2 \eta}{\beta} \right)
\| \nabla f(u) - \nabla f(v) \|^2
$$

In particular, for $\eta \leq \frac{2}{\beta}$ we have $\eta^2 - 2 \eta/\beta \leq 0$, which completes the proof.

Comment: The proof is quite nice. Thanks!